# Deleting an enter key value at the end of a char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a list of names from a text file I want to read in and then output back to another text file. ie:

```
101 Name 1
102 Name 2
103 Name 3
```

And for the code:

```
int studentID;
char name[MAX];
while (infile >> studentID)
      {
        infile.getline (name, MAX);
        outfile << left << setw(10) << studentID;
        outfile << left << setw(20) << name;
        outfile << left << setw(10) << "SKIPPED WORD";
      }
```

It will read in the enter key after the name from the text file, and then it will translate back to an enter key when I want to output it another text file and it will look like this.

```
101 Name 1
SKIPPED WORD
102 Name 2
SKIPPED WORD
103 Name 3
SkIPPED WORD
```

This is what I want

```
101 Name 1 SKIPPED WORD
102 Name 2 SKIPPED WORD
103 Name 3 SKIPPED WORD
```

Anyone knows how I can delete the 'enter' at the end of the char array?

Comment: What 'enter' at the end of the char array?  `getline` reads up to the next `'\n'`, which it extracts, but does _not_ store it.

Comment: You're not showing us the actual code.  What you've written will output _everything_ on a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this, the simplest is probably yo start using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `istream::getline`. `std::getline` reads the newline, but doesn't append it to the string.

Another solution is to simply check if the last character in the read string is a newline, and then change it to the string terminator character instead:

```
if (name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n')
    name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: I took the IF statement out and just went ahead and removed the last char of the array. Worked, thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary.  `istream::getline` will _not_ put a `'\n'` at the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `istream::getline`, use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which doesn't store the ending newline character in the string (but does remove it from the stream).

```
#include <string>

int studentID;
while (infile >> studentID)
{
    std::string name;
    std::getline(infile, name);

    outfile << left << setw(10) << studentID;
    outfile << left << setw(20) << name;
    outfile << left << setw(10) << "SKIPPED WORD" << '\n';
}
```

This way you don't need MAX anymore and can have arbitrarily long names.

Comment: The string still takes in the last char as an enter :(

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference.  Neither `istream::getline` nor the global `getline` store the delimiter.  There's something else wrong in his code.

Comment: @JamesKanze didn't know that, I just assumed `istream::getline` does that. Oops :)